# How long time before all the water in a lake has been replaced?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, water, flow, estimation

Studying hydrology, and in that context we've seen some information about lakes and the times it takes for the water to renew completely in them.
This got me interested in finding out how this is calculated normally in the real world and what assumptions are assumed.

Starting to analyze the issue and trying to figure out how to set up the mathematical equation for calculating this I made some assumptions based on data I believe you'd need in order to quantify these timings for real lakes.

**To have something to start with I quickly made up some numerical numbers that we'd normally need according to my best guess:**

Volume: $V = 10^6 m^3$

Discharge into lake: $Q_{in}  = 1.0 m^3/s$

Discharge out from lake: $Q_{out}  = 1.0 m^3/s$

We assume that newly added water needs 1 week ($3600 * 24 * 7 s = 604 800 s$) to circulate throughout the whole lake.

We know that residence time is then generally given by, and which in this example would give: $ T = V/Q = 10^6 s $

For example one assumes that a complete mixing of new water takes 5 months in a specific lake.
$

**Based on the above I make the following assumptions and try to conceptually imagine how one would set up such an equation based on  my current understanding of lake dynamics. I'm pretty certain that some simplifications have to be made, thus only approximating the real data:**

A lake collects the runoff from a catchment area and releases water. So if a lake has a volume of water that we assume is constant (which is the assumption over longer periods of time, like over a year), we are after the time it takes to replace that amount of water (equalling the total volume) with an equally sized volume of new water. So to simplify i'd say normal practice is to only consider discharge into (runoff from the whole runoff-area) the lake.

One generally knows that average residence time of water is given by the total volume of the lake divided by the discharge from the lake. So one can say that each molecule of water remains in the lake as long as is specified by the average residence time. But not all molecules leave the lake at once, so all the molecules would have been renewed after all of them have been discharged out of the lake. So when the discharge out of the lake multiplied by time equals the total volume of the lake, we can say all the water has been replaced. But this would only be a valid statement as long as the discharge in equals the discharge out. More correctly would then be to take the difference between the discharge in and out, and multiply this with a time that would result in and equal volume to the original one. Unless one does not assume a constant relationship between the discharges I imagine the calculations would become more tedious.

If one is to calculate how long time it takes before all the water in a lake has been replaced by new water, how would one go on about it?

Comment: The flow in a lake is not going to be uniform, so the water in some parts of the lake will have a much longer residense time than in others. There isn't any way to answer your question without specifying how the water flows.

Comment: Just added some numerical values to work with. We are to assume complete circulation after 1 week, the circulation is assumed complete for simplification.

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let x be the instantaneous mass fraction of original water remaining in the lake at time t, w be the mass recharge/discharge rate, and M be the total mass of water in the lake (assumed constant).  Also assume that the water in the lake is well-mixed.  Then, for a mass balance on the original water, we have:
$$M\frac{dx}{dt}=-wx$$or$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{x}{\tau}$$where $\tau=M/w$ is the mean residence time.  Initially, the mass fraction of original water is unity. So,$$x=e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$$After about 4 residence times, only about 2% of the original water molecules remain.